# How to pull different categories / use multiple queries in one page using WHERE statement from mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I posted a question here the other day and was kindly helped by a user but upon stumbling on another problem I have not been able to find out how to get it fixed.

I am trying to use this code to pull records from a database and although it works fine now, I am unable to get it to make multiple queries to the database in one document.

Here is the code:

```
This code is in the db config file.
---->This database query calls for all photos to be pulled from database!

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM photos ORDER BY value DESC"); 
$stmt->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Error '. $e->getMessage();
}

 ---->This database query calls for all photos from category one to be pulled from database
try {
$conn2 = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn2->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt2 = $conn2->prepare("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE type=1 ORDER BY value DESC"); 
$stmt2->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Error '. $e->getMessage();
}




This is the code on the page!


<!-- UGP holder -->
<div id="myDiv"></div>

<!-- UGP playlist -->
<div id="myPlaylist" style="display:none">

<!-- MAIN CATEGORY SHOWING ALL BOXES IN ORDER OF VALUE -->
    <ul data-category-name="ALL">



    <!-- CODE SNIPPET BELOW PULLS RECORDS FROM DATABASE FOR ALL PHOTOS-->



---> I would like this bit here to display ALL photos from database


<?php foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $p): ?>
<li data-url="link: <?= $p['link'] ?>" data-target="_blank">
    <img src="<?= $p['image'] ?>" alt="custom alt"/>
    <div data-thumbnail-content1="">
        <p class="centerDark"><?= $p['name'] ?></p>
        <p class="centerNormalDark"><?= $p['desc'] ?></p>
    </div>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>

       </ul>




    <ul data-category-name="PEOPLE" style="display:none">

    <!-- CODE SNIPPET BELOW PULLS RECORDS FROM DATABASE FOR CATEGORY ONE (TYPE=1) ONLY-->



  ---> I would like this bit here to display category one photos only from database



<?php foreach($stmt2->fetchAll() as $p): ?>
<li data-url="link: <?= $p['link'] ?>" data-target="_blank">
    <img src="<?= $p['image'] ?>" alt="custom alt"/>
    <div data-thumbnail-content1="">
        <p class="centerDark"><?= $p['name'] ?></p>
        <p class="centerNormalDark"><?= $p['desc'] ?></p>
    </div>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>


       </ul>
    <ul data-category-name="WILDLIFE">

    OTHER CODE SNIPPET HERE FOR NEXT CATEGORY AND SO ON

     </ul>
```

I'm not sure how to define each call to the database with a different id. I would like to show all photos in the first section but then to also show photos by each category in the other ones as seen in the code.

Also ....
Is there either a way to make one call to the database and then for the code to call each category from the initial database response to save server load or do I have to make a separate query each time for each category?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks
Justin

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use two separate connections for the two queries? Would it server your needs to simply create one connection and use it for both queries?

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for your response. I am not sure as I am not that great at coding yet but will have a large number of images which will be loaded using AJAX lazy load on scrolling.

How would I make one call to the database but then define the categories elsewhere? Is that possible? :>/

Comment: I'm not sure I can help you. You seem to be asking several different questions without a very clear explanation of any of them. Can you reduce this to a single question, "how do I do X" and an example of what you've tried to accomplish X that hasn't worked?

Comment: Maybe something like this? $stmt2 = $conn2->prepare("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE type IN (1,2,3,4,5) ORDER BY value DESC");

Comment: Hiya. Ok so I'm starting to understand the database queries side of things but how would I then write to call for each of the categories in the actual document? That's the bit I'm confused about. :/

Comment: American ... what I'm trying to work out is how to call the queries in the code snippets within the document?